# MySQL : LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - commands not working consistently

Tags: mysql

I am using the following code to upload a table in mysql:

```
mysql> create table my_db.woof (`start_g` VARCHAR(10) NULL,   `v_0` INT NULL,   `v_1` INT NULL); 
  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/edamame/test1_data.csv' INTO TABLE woof FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (start_g,v_0,v_1); 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The `test1_data.csv` looks like:

```
start_g,v_0,v_1
g1,11,12
g2,13,14
```

Even though there are no errors, no records are uploaded! Similar commands were working fine when uploading other tables ... did I miss anything in this specific case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... I figured it out ... the reason is some csv files hav line terminator as `\r\n` but some have `\n`.

Comment: `\r\n` will be for files generated in Windows and `\n` will be Linux and Unix based systems.